# Discord.js | TypeError: Cannot read property 'ban' of null

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

**Purpose:** To remove channel when they are created and then ban the member who created the channel.

**Code :**

```
bot.on('channelCreate', async (channel, member) => {
        if (!channel.guild)
            return;
        const audit = (await channel.guild.fetchAuditLogs()).entries.first();
        if (audit.action === 'CHANNEL_CREATE')
            if (audit.executor.id === '833382653779509288')
                return;
            channel.delete();
            channel.guild.member(executor).ban({reason: 'aaaaaa'})
    })`
```

**Result:** The channel is deleted but the user is not banned.

Here is the error :

```
(node:8388) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ban' of null
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\discordbot4\main.js:30:49)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:5)
(node:8388) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by 
rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8388) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Can someone help me fix this error?

Comment: What's the scope of `executor` in your `channel.guild.member(executor)`? Earlier you used `audit.executor`. Do you have some public variable `executor`, that's representing the User object?

Comment: the audit.executor.id was for the specified id to be ignored by the anti channel protection.

I think i should have used audit.executor.id in channel.guild.member(executor).

(I'm pretty new to js, just getting out of lua)

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

1. You are deleting the channel and then trying to access its `guild.member`. Do it in reverse order.
2. `User.ban()` returns a `Promise` objects, thus you should `await` it's results. ([docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban))
3. `bot.on('channelCreate',`  doesn't have any `member` parameter, just the `channel` ([docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-channelCreate))
4. With `fetchAuditLogs()` you can make use of `options`, such as `options.limit` set to 1. That way, you won't need that `.first()` method (and it should be a tad bit faster). ([docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchAuditLogs))

Comment: Should this be like this ?

```
bot.on('channelCreate', async channel => {
        if (!channel.guild)
            return;
        const audit = (await channel.guild.fetchAuditLogs()
        .then( audit => options.limit(1)))
        .catch(console.error)
        if (audit.action === 'CHANNEL_CREATE')
            if (audit.executor.id === '409699691408785411')
                return;
            (await channel.guild.member(audit.executor.id).ban({reason: 'aaaaaa'}))
            channel.delete();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code but with (most of) the suggestions from @Gaben.

```js
bot.on('channelCreate', async (channel) => {
  if (!channel.guild) return;
  const audit =
    ( await channel.guild.fetchAuditLogs() ).entries.first();
  if (
    audit.action === 'CHANNEL_CREATE' &&
    audit.executor.id === '833382653779509288'
  ) return;
  channel.guild.member(executor).ban({
    reason: 'aaaaaa'
  });
  await channel.delete();
});
```

I have never used `Discord.js` which is why I wasn't comfortable changing up the code too much.

---

I just noticed how your error looks compared to your code, and I think I know the problem.
The error says, `Cannot read property "ban" of null,` which I think means that `channel.guild.member(executor)` is returning `null`. Looking at the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member), I can see that the `.member(user)` function returns a `GuildMember` if found, otherwise it returns `null`.
So from what I can tell, `channel.guild.member(executor)` is null... it seems that `executor` is not actually what you think it is.

Comment: First, thanks you for the answer, I tried the code and unfortunatelly, this is not working.

I changed channel.guild.member(executor).ban to channel.guild.member(audit.executor.id).ban but this is also not working.

Does you have any answer to this ?

Comment: Yah sorry, I've never used discord.js before. I was basically just copying @Gaben's suggestions and putting them into code form.

Comment: @Mengo_ I just noticed your error and changed my answer.